# Pre-images of Seifert surfaces are incompressible?

Tags: 3-manifolds, branched-covers, seifert-surfaces

Consider a knot $K \subset S^3$ and let $M_K$ be the associated double branched cover. The pre-image $S$ of a Seifert surface is a surface without boundary inside $M_K$.

Can $S$ be incompressible? If yes, how is this related to the topology of $K$?

I'm particularly interested in the case where $M_K$ is hyperbolic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The incompressible Seifert surface $\Sigma$ will have incompressible preimage $S$ in the double branched cover if and only if the complement of a tubular neighborhood of $\Sigma$ in $S^3$ has incompressible boundary. This condition was termed "partially unknotted" by [Jaco](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=754723).

Examples of Seifert surfaces which are *not* partially unknotted were claimed by Jaco in the paper, but not explicitly described. 
The simplest examples can be obtained by taking a knotted handlebody with hyperbolic complement, such as Thurston's knotted wye.

[image]

See also [Adams-Reid](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1231698) for descriptions of knotted genus 2 handlebodies (with incompressible hyperbolic complements).

Now, draw a knot on this handlebody which bounds a genus 1 Seifert surface $\Sigma$, using the fact that for a genus one surface $\Sigma$, $\Sigma\times [0,1]$ is a genus 2 handlebody. Any such knot will have a Seifert surface which is not partially unknotted.